# How do I find and list folders with a specific folder name, containing files modified recently?

Tags: shell, find, busybox, ash, synology

I have a set of folders that are regularly updated, which I would like to regularly parse through and update to a simple text file list. This list gets used with rsync so I shorten the file names using sed for easy syncing.

They are set up pretty much like this:

- software_folder

  - software_version_1

    - version_1.1

      - some_files
    - version_BETA

      - some_files
  - software_version_2

    - version_2.2

      - some_files
    - version_BETA

      - some_files

I've tried something like:

```
for dir in `find -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '*BETA'`; do test `find $dir -type f -mtime -1` | echo $dir | sed "s|^\./||" >> list.txt; done
```

But the output is still listing all BETA folders (and gives an 'unknown operand' error on `.aspx` files?).

It would be a bonus if the script could move on to the next folder after it finds a minimum of one modified file and updates the folder list, just so it doesn't have to iterate through the rest of the files per folder.

Comment: There is a package called `tree` on many distributions which may help you.

Comment: If you run that (just type `tree` inside your directory) you get the contents of your directories listed like you have set out.  I'm not sure how you wish to combine that with rsync. It's fast enough that it seems unlikely optimizing with a script to detect changes early would be worth it.

Comment: Thank you, however the synology NAS I am working with doesn't support tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all `*BETA` directories that have new files in them (`-mtime -1`) and save those directories names in `list.txt`, try:

```
find -type f -path '*BETA/*' -mtime -1 | sed 's|^\./||; s|BETA/.*|BETA|' | sort -u >list.txt
```

Since your goal is to create newline-separated data in the file `list.txt`, that must mean that you do not expect any of the directories or files to have names which themselves contain newline characters.  If they did, then, of course, a different output format would be needed.

#### How it works

- `find -type f -path '*BETA/*' -mtime -1`

  This finds all new files which have a parent directory, somewhere in the path, whose name ends in `BETA` when new is defined by find's conventions for `-mtime -1`.
- `sed 's|^\./||; s|BETA/.*|BETA|'`

  This removes the initial `./` from the file names and also removes everything after the `BETA`.  The result is the name of the BETA directory.
- `sort -u`

  The directory list that `sed` creates will have duplicates.  This removes duplicates.
- `>list.txt`

  This saves the output in `list.txt`

#### More general solution

The following approach is safe even if directories or files have newline characters in their names (this may require GNU tools):

```
find -type f -path '*BETA/*' -mtime -1 -print0 | sed -z 's|^\./||; s|BETA/.*|BETA|' | sort -zu >list.out
```

This creates a file `list.out` which has the directory names in nul-separated form.  Since the nul character can never appear in a file or directory name, this is a safe approach.  To use `list.out`, you would, of course, need to read it with a tool that understands nul-separated input.

Comment: I gave this a go, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any output.  
`find -type f -path '*BETA/*' -mtime -1`  
Testing that and the other versions by itself seems to have no results.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe there aren't any files new enough.  Try `find . -type f -path '*BETA/*'` and `find . -type d -path '*BETA' `

Comment: I see from the comments that you are on a Synology NAS.  You might check its documentation to see what features its `find` supports or doesn't support.

Comment: Thank you, I got it with this: `find -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime -1 -name '*BETA*' | sed "s|^\./||" > ~/list.txt`